# Illustrator CS6 Rotating a path after Arcing (Warping)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

After I Arc a Path using the Warp tool to the desired Arc size radius etc. I then want to rotate the arc so that it is inverted.
However when I flip or rotate it 180 degrees, the Arc returns to the original shape even thought the Original Rectangle path has rotated.

Is there a way to do this so that the Arc stays locked to the original rectangle it was based on?
Thanks in advance,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to expand the effect you applied to your path. This causes the path to actually change to the appearance you see with the effect, rather than being the original rectangle with the effect still applied.

Choose `Object > Expand Appearance` while your object is selected to expand it.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to apply the Arc warp to an object:

1. `Effect > Warp > Arc`
2. `Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Warp > Arc`

If you use #1 above, then the effect is created **relative to the artboard**. This means is you rotate or distort the object with the effect applied, the effect *remains relative to the artboard edges* and will **not** rotate with the object. As [Bakabaka](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/5498/bakabaka) answered, if you use `Object > Expand Appearance` after applying the effect, you "bake in" the effect making it no longer editable and it will then rotate with the object.

If you wish to **retain the live aspect of the warp so it can be edited again later if needed, AND have it relative to the object** use #2 above. This applies the distortion (warp) relative to the object, not the artboard. This way the envelope is still editable regardless of how you may transform the object. There's no need to expand the appearance if you use the Envelope Distort rather than the effect.

I rarely use the Effect due to this very vast difference in the relationship of the distortion to the object.